# How can I fix STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION by Vec<T> allocation?

Tags: windows, rust, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to allocate a struct containing Vec with the global allocator.
(To simplify this problem, use Vec here.)
It seems that an error may occur when allocating Vec using the std::alloc::alloc function.

How should I fix it in Unsafe Rust?

```
#[test]
fn allocation() {
    let layout = std::alloc::Layout::new::<Vec<u32>>();
    let ptr = unsafe{ std::alloc::alloc(layout) } as *mut Vec<u32>;
    dbg!(ptr);
    let ptr_ref = unsafe{ &mut *ptr  as &mut Vec<u32> };
    ptr_ref.resize_with(16, || {
        dbg!("initializing");
        0
    });
    dbg!(&ptr_ref[0] as *const u32);
    unsafe{ std::alloc::dealloc( ptr as *mut u8, layout); }
}
```

When run the above code, it sometimes ends with "0xc0000005, STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION" or "0xc0000374, STATUS_HEAP_CORRUPTION".
Also, when these errors occur, it seems that initialization (closure that returns the initial value) has not been executed.

---

Edit:

It seems that my code didn't include the initialization of Vec. JMAA's answer gives details. So I added the following code before casting to `&mut Vec<u32>`.

```
unsafe {
    std::ptr::write(ptr, Vec::with_capacity(16));
}
```

The details of the `std::ptr::write` function are [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.write.html).
This seems to work fine.

Comment: It's unclear what you are ultimately trying to do here. "allocating a vec on the heap" means to allocate the control block (which holds the pointer for the actual allocation) on the heap. This is equivalent to `Box<Vec<T>>`. Can't you just use `Box::into_raw()`?

Comment: @user2722968 This code is part of the parallel processing code, and Vec<T> can be owned by multiple variables as pointers. It is also dropped by mechanism other than reference counting, such as `std::sync::Arc`. So I don't think `Box<Vec<T>>` is suitable.

Comment: @folt This sounds like a _very_ bad idea unless you absolutely know what you're doing and (apologies if my assumption is wrong here) from your code it appears that you do not. Rust has rules about aliasing, mutability, and ownership that the compiler uses to make assumptions. If you violate these rules, the code is wrong and may not behave as expected. You can use `unsafe` to temporarily stop the compiler from _checking_ these rules itself, but it will still assume you've followed them and continue to make assumptions based on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, so I think there are a couple of different issues to unpack here.

First you need to understand what a `Vec` is. A `Vec` is not like a C-style array, but rather more like a C++ `std::vector`. The `Vec` object itself just contains two items (often called the "control block"): a wide pointer to the heap-allocated space for the elements of the `Vec` (including the allocated capacity), and the current length of the `Vec`. The actual elements of the `Vec` exist elsewhere, in memory allocated by the `Vec` itself and pointed to by that wide pointer it holds in the control block.

So, in you code `ptr` points to a region of heap memory allocated with enough space to hold a `Vec` object, that is to hold the control block. You never actually initialise a `Vec` object, just allocate enough memory to hold one.

Then you do your first "bad thing", you cast `ptr` to a `&mut Vec`. But you never initialised a `Vec` object there (i.e., the allocated memory for the control block has not been initialised). References in Rust cannot point to uninitialised memory, doing violates safety and your whole program is invalid. In particular, you call the `resize_with` method on a "`Vec`", but there is **no `Vec` there**, just some block of heap memory with the size and alignment to theoretically hold a `Vec`'s control block.

What I suppose you think you're doing is that the pointer to `Vec` doesn't point at the control block, but directly to the heap memory containing the elements of the `Vec`. This would make some sense of why you try to `dealloc` the way that you do, with a pointer to the first element of the `Vec` rather than the `Vec` itself. That is also wrong, since that isn't pointing at the memory you `alloc`'d.

---

So what *should* you be doing? I'm not an expert because I've never felt the need to manually de/allocate in Rust before, but my understanding is that you can simply do `*ptr = Vec::new()` (or whatever `Vec` constructor you want) and then you can cast back to a `&mut Vec` since there's now an initialised `Vec` there.

Then, when you're done you fist need to make sure that the `Vec` gets dropped -- this will cause it to internally deallocate the space allocated for the elements -- before you do `dealloc(ptr.cast(), layout)`.

Comment: I think your point is correct and I understand what mean by your "very bad idea". On the other hand, I need to temporarily stop checking drops like raw Vec<T>. I wanted to reuse the Vec<T> implementation, but it may be unsuitable to use Vec<T>.

Comment: I would advise you ask (in a separate question), "How do I achieve X in Rust?" where X is your problem, not your current attempt at a solution. There are lots of safe and ergonomic ways of doing parallel work in Rust. From what I've seen here you appear to be coming from a C background and attempting to replicate those methods, but that will not work here. I'm trying to save you from yourself.

Comment: I thought resize_with would reallocate including initialization, so it seems I made a mistake. I've been developing with Rust for over 2 years and am currently implementing a lock-free structure. So blocking structures like Mutex weren't available. It seems impossible manually Vec<T> allocation. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to control where the contents of the Vec are allocated, you can use the [experimental allocator API](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.new_in). I'd advise you move very slowly and read a lot (esp. the [rustonomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/)). You made some very basic mistakes in the code you posted which suggests you're new to this, and doing this stuff manually and correctly isn't easy.